# Swipe To Edit Details Swift and Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am having trouble passing data to a new view controller to edit the fields when using a RowAction button.

I can get the RowAction button to go to the new view controller via the code below:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?  {

    var editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: " Edit " , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("EditDetails", sender: self)
        }   
    })
    return [editAction]
}
```

I can get the data to pass using a normal segue using the code below:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "EditDetails") {
        [segue destinationViewController].
        var editView = segue.destinationViewController as! EditDetailsTableViewController

    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let row = Int(indexPath.row)
            editView.currentObject = objects[row] as? PFObject
        }

    }
}
```

However, I cannot seem to do both at the same time. I would like a user to be able to click the Edit button and the details for those fields populate and they can edit them.

Adding in proposed solution...however, still getting nil passed.

```
var editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: " Edit " , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

       let objectToEdit = self.objects[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("EditDetails", sender: objectToEdit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to pass values from some object in that row such as a textField? You can just save the current indexPath and grab them directly if there is some textField value you are needing or pass the row as sender in

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("EditDetails", sender: cell) // get the cell from the indexPath or just pass the indexPath
```

Then you can use that in prepareForSegue

Comment: I tried your solution above, however, I am still passing nil. I added my code for trying your solution in my original question at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. Check out the thread. At the bottom is my own answer.

[Table row action to segue with indexPath row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385858/table-row-action-to-segue-with-indexpath-row/32386005#32386005)

Just send the indexPath, and then use it in the prepareForSegue to make it work.

Comment: Please don't post link only answers to other Stack Overflow questions. Instead, vote/flag to close this question as a duplicate, or, if it is not a duplicate, *tailor your answer to this specific question.*