# Table row action to segue with indexPath row

Tags: ios, swift, action, cell

So I have a table view and a Custom VC.
then I have an object exercises with `detailImage` as property.
How can I get the `indexPath.row` from the table row action into my `prepareForSegue` function?

this returns `nil`: `self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detailsSegue" {            
          if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
             let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
             print(self.exercises[indexPath.row].image)
             destinationController.detailImage = self.exercises[indexPath.row].image
             print ("send")
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't with table row actions. You handle it with the action itself. See my example here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27856196/4339121 at the bottom is a swift version

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this in your code:

```
if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
```

Try this:

```
if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
```

Comment: I get " Invalid use of "()" to call a value of non-function type "NSIndexPath" and the build fails.

Comment: Is the Custom VC the DataSource and Delegate for the Table View?

Comment: From the main VC where the editActionAtRow resides, it has DataSource and Deletate connected to that table view.

Comment: A few more questions - Which version of Swift / Xcode are you using?  Is the main VC a subclass of UITableViewController, or UIViewController?  If it's UIViewController, have you made an Outlet for the tableView?

Comment: I use the latest beta Version 7.0 beta 6 (7A192o)
Its a subclass of UITableViewController.
Sorry for being so noob about it...

Comment: It seems like for some reason it's not recognizing "self" as a UITableViewController.  Try this:

1) Connect the TableView in interface builder to an IBOutlet
2) Instead of calling self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow, use the new outlet name instead of tableView.

For example - create an outlet for the TableView named myTable, then in the segue use --- if let indexPath = self.myTable.indexPathForSelectedRow() {}

Comment: So I in the main swift file I created an outlet myTable and connected the TableView from main VC with that outlet. 
In the swift file, I did as you saig:
if let indexPath = self.myTable.indexPathForSelectedRow() {} and got the same error as before:  Invalid use of "()" to call a value of non-function type "NSIndexPath".
Not sure what else I can do.
http://oi61.tinypic.com/2hojw2h.jpg

Comment: Without seeing the whole code for the class, I wouldn't know where else to look.

Comment: For me removing the parens worked, for iOS 9. `if let index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {}`

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the sender object in `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`
I got it to work. It's maybe a dirty solution but it works.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let detailsAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Details", handler: {(action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detailsSegue", sender: indexPath) //sender is the indexPath
        }
    )
```

and then in the `prepareForSegue`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detailsSegue" {
        let indexPath = sender!
        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        print(self.exercises[indexPath.row].image)
```

There is probably a better way..Anyone to comment?