# Swipe to edit details using Segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, uitableviewrowaction

I'm new to IOS development and swift so I'm a bit confused. Building on this question

[Swipe To Edit Details Swift and Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659847/swipe-to-edit-details-swift-and-parse)

I have a table cell that I swipe and when I click edit, I want it to go to another page to edit the details. When i don't have a segue, it asks for one as an error. When I put one (going from prototype cell > edit page), it works, except now it goes there when I click on the cell in addition to swipe.

I just want it to Edit only on swipe. How would one do that?

- Am I supposed to suppress the default action of the segue in `prepareForSegue` so that `EditDetails` segue gets triggered only when I tell it to (like below)?

  ```
  var editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Edit" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
          self.performSegueWithIdentifier("EditDetails", sender: tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath))
      }   
  })
  editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
  ```
- Am I supposed to create the segue in code instead of through the UI, so it doesn't add any additional actions that I don't need?

Comment: Create the segue in the storyboard, but from the view controller itself, not the prototype cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewController A: where you have the cell
ViewController B: the viewController what you would like to present.

On the storyboard, click on viewController A, press and hold CTRL, and drag the blue line to ViewController B. Choose "show" segue.

[image]

Click on the segue, and lets name it "EditDetails"

[image]

Now you got the segue set up. After this, you should call:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("EditDetails", sender: self)
```

instead of calling this

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("EditDetails", sender: tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath))
```

Reason:
it is the viewController, which will perform the segue, not the tableViewCell.

Comment: genius! didn't know you could create a segue from that side panel. thanks for the awesome descriptive answer.